# Create a histogram with stacked bars

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am creating a histogram this way:

```
selected_features = ["HOUR","CLUSTER"]
plt.figure(1)
plt.hist(df[selected_features].values[:,0])
plt.title("HOUR")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

The values of `CLUSTER` are 0 or 1.

Now I want to transform each bar into a stacked bar with 2 areas (let's say red and green colored) in order to show the distribution of `CLUSTER` values for each bar. How can I do it?

EDIT:

I tried this, but it gives me the error `ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 9 or scalar`:

```
N=9
ind = np.arange(N)    # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35

p1 = plt.bar(ind, df[df["CLUSTER"]==0][['HOUR']],color='r')
p2 = plt.bar(ind, df[df["CLUSTER"]==1][['HOUR']],color='y')

plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('0', '1'))

plt.show()
```

DATA:

```
s_hour = pd.Series(["5","5","5","8","8","9","10"]) 
s_cluster = pd.Series(["1","1","0","1","0","1","0"])  

df = pd.concat([s_hour, s_cluster], axis=1)
df
```

Comment: This may help: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html

Comment: @cel: Thanks. Indeed I've checked this tutorial and tried to apply it to my case, but it gives me an error message (see my edit).

Comment: Can you please provide also your data?

Comment: @DimKoim: Ok, please see my last edit.

Comment: @cel: In my opinion this solution is overcomplicated for my case. I found another (simpler) solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way:

```
filter = df["CLUSTER"] == 1
plt.hist([df["HOUR"][filter],df["HOUR"][~filter]],stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, it would be good to accept either your own or eyllanescs solution such this question is not left in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I'd like to accept mine, but I can only do it in 2 days because of the rules of Stackoverflow